# Terminal font breaks after exiting vim

Tags: terminal, vim, fonts, zsh

My terminal's (alacrity with zsh/powerlevel10k) font breaks after I leave vim.

Anyone that could tell me how I could fix this?

[image: Image of broken font]

Interestingly, the font seems to fix itself if I enter and then exit vim again.

I'm using alacrity terminal on arch, using the Meslo Nerd Font packed with powerlevel10k with the fancy symbols option in zsh.

Both vim and neovim seem to show this behaviour.

Comment: How about other editors, such as `nano` or `emacs -nw`? Do you have to actually do something in the editor (changing something, scrolling through the file,....), or is it enough to start and terminate the editor to see the effect?

Comment: Starting the editor is enough, nano doesn't break, haven't tried emacs.

Comment: Does the effect also occur when you start vim from a bash shell?

Comment: How about opening a bug report at [alacrity](https://github.com/alacritty/alacritty/issues)? My guess is that vim is sending some escape code when starting up, which gets misinterpreted by the terminal emulator. You could also, for comparision, try a different terminal program. If it works there, the problem is really in Alacrity.

Comment: Well this is a little embarrassing, but I just started my laptop and the problem seems to have disappeared on its own... Thanks for the help though, appreciated!

Comment: This is creepy. So basically you just have rebooted ArchLinux, but did not run any updates?

Comment: Yeah, not as far as I know though I wouldn't remember. At the very least I did nothing to anything vim related besides maybe open vimtutor at some point..